# Run-on, comma splice or just too many clauses?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm grading my student's paper and this is his sentence:

**Without wasting any time, Lady Osbourne took the boys with her after bribing the head lady and they set off in a fleet of luxurious cars back to her home which was located amid the most elite neighbourhood full of wealthy business tycoons.**

Is his biggest mistake too many clauses in one sentence? Or is it a run-on or a comma-splice?

My instinct says that I should tell him to simplify his sentence, and separate the clauses. Should I follow my instinct?

Comment: It's grammatical. But then so is 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously.'  _And there are other tests for acceptability._ (a) Does 'Without wasting any time, Lady Osbourne took the boys with her after bribing the head lady' work logically? I'd re-order to 'Lady O bribed the head lady, then without wasting any time took the boys [off?] [away?] with her.' (b) I agree that the sentence is very unwieldy, but I'll hazard that two sentences is best here, to compartmentalise 3+ different scenes. 'They set off in a fleet of luxurious cars back to her home – a mansion located ...

Comment: in the most elite neighbourhood, full of wealthy business magnates.' // The writer is writing to impress, deciding (like Dickens) that good writing is a function of sentence length (but wrongly assuming that the longer the sentence, the better the prose) and choosing the more erudite synonym even where incorrect (amid; tycoons) (though 'magnate', stylishly better, and pretty upper-register, might well not have been considered).

Comment: It could be better, though it's not all that bad.

Comment: Thank you @Edwin. Clearly I need to spend more time familiarising myself with grammatical structure.

Comment: You can hardly chastise your student for writing a long sentence, when our greatest writer Charles Dickens regularly did the same thing! Nevertheless, I would drop the "which was" since it's not needed and its omission would improve the readability.

Answer (score 1):

It needs a comma after the "head lady" and another after "her home."

But it is certainly unwieldy even after those commas are added.